# Combine Bibliography and Reference

Tags: bibliographies, cross-referencing, texstudio

[image]

The LaTex file was made by someone else, now I'm trying to make some modifications to the file.

Q1. The .pdf file generated from .tex only containes the Bibliography part. The reference is in the cite.sty as shown in the picture. How do I combine them together to generate a complete .pdf file?

Q2. The first page of the .pdf file generated from TexStudio is a blank page. How do I delete this page?

Thanks very much.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: For Q2, some PDF viewers are able to delete individual pages. For Q1, I am sorry but I do not understand what *bibliography* and *reference* indicate respectively. (Are not they the same?) The answer might be as simple as `\include{cite.sty}` at somewhere. But I am not sure unless there are more hints.